# Remove protection in Excel using Microsoft Information Protection SDK to import these files to my .NET application

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, sdk, microsoft-information-protection

I've been trying to import a protected excel into my custom VB.NET Winform application, but it's failing since this excel is protected. I can import the file into the application by changing to unrestricted access and changing the sensitivity labels. I want all of this to be taken care by .Net application itself. I have been told to integrate the Microsoft Information Protection (MIP) SDK into my application to fix this issue and I've been told to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip. This has got a lot of information. Can someone please tell me how I can get the issue fixed?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Microsoft Information Protection (MIP) SDK setup and configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip). Look towards the bottom where it states: _...when you're ready to get some experience with the SDK, start with [Quickstart: Client application initialization (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/quick-app-initialization-csharp)_. It sounds like you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Quickstart in the other reply and this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MipSDK-File-Dotnet

Once you have all of the overhead done (Context, Profile, Engine), then you can do one of two things:

1. Use the RemoveProtection() API to decrypt the file.
2. Use the GetTemporaryDecryptedStream() or GetTemporaryDecryptedFile() API to create a temp decrypted output to render in your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ifilehandler.getdecryptedtemporaryfileasync?view=mipsdk-dotnet-1.12#microsoft-informationprotection-file-ifilehandler-getdecryptedtemporaryfileasync